# How do I get the module installed with the python library working - Google client library for python - unable to find module

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm on developers.google.com and trying out the Python Quickstart to create a simple Python command-line application that makes requests to the Drive API. 
I have gone trough all steps however I get the following error

```
~/Pythondev/apidev$ python quickstart.py Traceback (most recent call    last):
 File "quickstart.py", line 4, in <module>
 from googleapiclient.discovery import build
 ImportError: No module named googleapiclient.discovery
```

I have tried this on Windows 10 as well as Linux , and I end up with the same error 
What could be the cause ?

pip installed the library without any error messages.

> > > import googleapiclient, httplib2, oauth2client
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'googleapiclient'

Running the quickstart.py file showed the above error.

Running import googleapiclient on the python console gives the same error

This is a link to the page on google developers :
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the list of installed packages by typing: `pip3 list | grep google` ?

Comment: google-api-python-client 1.7.11 
google-auth              1.6.3  
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3                                                                                                      I am running python 2 , this is the result of  pip2 list | grep goolge

Comment: Weird. I just did install all mentioned in section 2 (Google Drive Python Quickstart) packages and there was no problem with imports (Debian 9, Python 2.7.13).

Comment: You may have local directory called `googleapiclient` in your current dir.
Create a new dir, cd into it and try import from python console.
BTW, could you see what you have set in `$PYTHONPATH` and `$PYTHONHOME` ?